# Who is he and what game is he in?

Tags: game-identification

[image]
It is an imaginare game and it has 2 series and a 3rd part will come very soon but the picture isn't the first character and game is first person game

Comment: @Vemonus I think game identifcation may be applicable here, I agree though that it should also have the game's name, although considering the persian text in game, it may be in persian also.

Comment: @Aequitas true. I was thinking there might be some sort of online guide that we could find if the name of the game was there, though. Also, I'm wondering if the Arabic text is actually a hint and the question text is a translation.

Comment: So that guy pictured behind the tiles is "from" a game? Seems like it would be a video/photo based game then, like Tex Murphy or a hidden pictures game maybe...

Answer (score 12):

It's one of the paintings of [Cave Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cave_Johnson_(Portal)) from Portal 2.

[image: Picture of Cave Johnson]

Comment: [Cave Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cave_Johnson_(Portal)) appears to the correct answer

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how you were able to figure this out, but you may want to add a picture. @Wondercricket beat me to posting the wiki link, but that'd be a good source.

Comment: Ah, yep, that Wikipedia link might be a bit better.

Comment: (I honestly just recognized the face/picture, though I double-checked.)